# If $\|X(t)\|\leq M$, does this imply that $det(X(t))$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I am wondering if the following is true:

If you are given a matrix $X(t)$ (that depends on the positive real variable $t$)  which is bounded (i.e, $\|X(t)\|\leq M$ for all $t$. Can you conclude that $\det(X(t))$ is also bounded? Can you also conclude that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\det(X(t))$ is finite? Thanks!

Comment: I was sorry to see you deleted your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060538/if-the-limit-matrix-of-a-linear-system-has-eigenvalues-of-negative-real-part-th; I had actually spent a lot of time on it and had a partial, tho' not complete, solution.  Did you find a proof or counterxample?  If so, I'd like to see it!  This question interests me a *lot*, for professional reasons, so if you have any information, I'd love to hear from you.  You can message me through MSE by leaving a comment somewhwere, or use the email address on my user page.  Cheers!

Comment: @Robert Lewis: Please see the answer in: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983774/limit-of-solution-of-linear-system-of-odes-as-t-to-infty/1061480?noredirect=1#comment2160412_1061480

Comment: @RobertLewis: Please see the answer at:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983774/limit-of-solution-of-linear-system-of-odes-as-t-to-infty/1061480?noredirect=1#comment2160412_1061480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the determinant is a continuous function of the entries of a matrix

Comment: What do you mean by your answer? Do you mean: $\lim_{t\to \infty}det(X(t))=det(\lim_{t\to \infty}X(t))$? But, how does that prove that $\lim_{t\to \infty}det(X(t))$ is finite if the norm of $X(t)$ is bounded?

Comment: whatever norm it is, it is equivalent to the max-norm, so you can assume $|x_{ij}(t)| \leq M$ for all $i,j$

Answer (score 3):

Warning: $\det(X(t))$ is bounded (answer by Student), but this does not guarantee the existence of $\lim_{t\to\infty}\det(X(t))$. Trivial $1\times 1$ example: $(\sin(t))$.